# Is it possible to implement multiple interface pods in Azure kubernetes service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, networking, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to implement multi interface pods in azure kubernetes service. It seems like multus is not supported in aks([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/580166/azure-aks-multus-support.html#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20some%20other%20discussion,not%20supported%20by%20AKS%20yet.)). Is there any other way to achieve this. If possible what network policy and network configurations should be used?

Comment: Can you share why you need multiple interfaces on AKS?

Comment: I am trying to deploy 5gcore(open5gs) in aks. I need multiple interface to seperate the data plane and control plane traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available today with Azure CNI. Also, there is no work around to implement multus or any other CNI like calico with AKS. Having said that, you can do provide your feedback here in this [feature request form](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/?q=kubernetes%20pods) for its future availability.